# Returning objects from Ruby Classes

Tags: ruby, class

I'm convinced I've had this working before!

I have the following class. The title string is created within the class the fname and lname strings are passed in as parameters. However, I can't seem to ever get the @title object to return anything other than nil.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :fname, :lname, :title

  def initialize(fname, lname)
    @fname = fname
    @lname = lname
    @title = title
  end

  def string1
    @lname + ", " + @fname
  end

  @title = "Director"

  def string2
    @title
  end

end

p = Person.new("Yukihiro", "Matsumoto")

p p.string1
p p.string2
```

Comment: Nutshell: `@title` is a class instance variable, `string2` is an instance method; the two are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code:

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :fname, :lname

  def initialize(fname, lname)
    @fname = fname
    @lname = lname
  end

  def string1
    @lname + ", " + @fname
  end

  def title
    @@title
  end

  @@title = "Director"

  def string2
    @@title
  end

end

p = Person.new("Yukihiro", "Matsumoto")

p p.string1
p p.string2
```

gives the following output when run with Ruby 1.9.3:

```
"Matsumoto, Yukihiro"
"Director"
```

I've assumed that you want to keep the title the same for all the objects you create. If not, then [iamnotmaynard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1735262/iamnotmaynard)'s answer is what you're after.

Comment: Thanks Matt - Actually in my working code the title is dynamic and is data returned from a request to a Web Service. However, this worked great. Weird thing is I'm sure I've done this before without having to use double @@ variables!

Answer (score 2):

Within the context of your class, `@title` refers to the class instance variable. Within the context of an instance method, `@title` refers to an instance variable. You're confusing these two.

What you need instead is a lazy initializer if you have some kind of default that you need applied:

```
def title
  @title ||= "Director"
end
```

Or better, to populate it in the first place. One way to fix this is to augment your initialize method:

```
def initialize(fname, lname, title = nil)
  @fname = fname
  @lname = lname
  @title = title || "Director"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing `title` to the constructor. You need to have something along the lines of

```
def initialize(fname, lname, title)
    @fname = fname
    @lname = lname
    @title = title
end
```

and call it with

```
p = Person.new("Yukihiro", "Matsumoto", "sensei")
```

The line `@title = "Director"` is executed during the class definition, which sets the variable on the class `Person` itself, rather than during the construction of an instance of the class, which is why the instance variable `@title` is not being set to "Director" in the new object you create with `Person.new`.

In fact, here's how to show that this is what's happening. Adding this method

```
class Person
    def self.string3
        @title
    end
end
```

adds a class method to `Person` to get the class's instance variable that was set during the class definition:

```
>> p Person.string3
"Director"
```

Comment: Classes are objects too - they can have instance variables (which are completely distinct from the instance variable of any instances of that class)

Comment: @FrederickCheung I'd used class variables but not instance variables on classes, but of course those exist too because everything's an object.